# Questions about time derivative of jacobian matrix

Tags: matlab, jacobian, matrix

I find that in some robotic toolboxs(e.g. FROST https://ayonga.github.io/frost-dev/index.html) they use

[image]

to calculate time derivative of jacobian matrix.

Here is my guess about the reason of using this formula:

[image]

if this is right, could anyone please tell me how to prove this part which shows that derivative and partial derivative can exchange?
[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the partial differentiation you can get to that expression as

\begin{align}
\frac{dJ}{dt} &= \frac{\partial J}{\partial q}\frac{\partial q}{\partial t} \\
\frac{dJ}{dt} &= \frac{\partial J}{\partial q}\frac{d q}{d t}\\
\frac{dJ}{dt} &= \frac{\partial (J \dot q)}{\partial q}
\end{align}

In the last line $\dot q$ is a constant that can enter the partial differentiation part.

Comment: Hi jdios, thanks a lot for your quick reply，now I understand the formula of calculating dJ/dt! I still have a question which is:  Can time derivative and partial derivative exchange? (the formula in the third image) Thanks in advance again.

Comment: @BrPAl If the Jacobian is differentiable w.r.t. time then [Schwarz' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Sufficiency_of_twice-differentiability) should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tobias, I will check it later.